# pandas group by as_index=False not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

i have a pandas data frame with multiple rows repeated with one column varying for e.g

```
  name  id  company
0   A   1   microsoft
1   A   1   google
2   A   1   amazon
3   B   2   cn
4   B   2   jetix
5   C   3   icc
```

consider rows represnt students,
we need to group rows on unique column for all related set of rows,
consider **id** as one unqiue for every student/employee

when executed the below code i got the following output

```
df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.dropna())
```

**Output**

```
   id   name                 company
0   1   [A, A, A]   [microsoft, google, amazon]
1   2   [B, B]      [cn, jetix]
2   3    C          icc
```

i am using the same above code shown, for other file, the file is an excel file, when i read an excel file in a jupyter notebook, with `(534*60)` and did above `groupby.agg()` i got `(75*60)`

when i execute the same in a flow , where some operations are done on dataframe like fill nans  with empty strings etc, i am getting following output

```
df.groupby(key,as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.dropna())

Exception Shape of passed values is (60, 75), indices imply (59, 75) occured in function <class 'method'>
```

i used `as_index=False` but i am still getting this only

the input shape is `534*60` can some one help me with this

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces this error?

Comment: hey i  have added the above example for you to understand

Comment: Your example does not reproduce the error.

Comment: beacsue i am not able to know what exactly is the error, when i download the file, and execute its working fine

Answer (score 0):

[`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) is not an aggregation operation, you should explicitly perform the conversion to list:

```
df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg(lambda x: list(x.dropna()))
```

Output:

```
   id       name                      company
0   1  [A, A, A]  [microsoft, google, amazon]
1   2     [B, B]                  [cn, jetix]
2   3        [C]                        [icc]
```

Comment: i am sorry, when i  used the above, i am getting orginal 534 rows as ouptut as it is orginal as  above file

Comment: if aggregate hasnt been working why does 534rows comes to 75 rows and columns became from 60 to 59

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that give an error? Your file if you cannot generate one

Comment: i am sorry i couldnt share the file, its policy